# How to secure a Scala Play Endpoint with a JWT Token

Tags: scala, playframework, jwt

What would be a good way to implement jwt-auth for a scala play project.

I couldnt find any recent resources so i hope someone can give some directions on what to do or where to look

regards

Moritz

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can have a look on [Silhouette](https://www.silhouette.rocks/docs/config-authenticators#jwtauthenticator)